# All Privileges screen CSS bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There seems to be a bug on the all privileges screen. Css float problem?

[image]

Comment: Looks like this has been completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it looks like the following CSS needs to be added:

```
.related a {
    clear: left; 
}
```